# How to send objects from server to client side components in react-express node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

How can I send JS objects from `Express` backend to client side `React` components?

I can send simple variables by setting them in `res.locals` or `cookies`, but for larger objects, how do I do it?

Not in favor of API as it leads to the page to load and then request makes user wait on the screen. My details are available as soon as server is started.

**Code flow in brief:**

Its a [kraken](http://krakenjs.com) app, and in server side, if I do,

`router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'))`,

`ejs` is set as view engine in express config, it will return index file to browser with the react code bundled out by `webpack` added to it.

Comment: Could you give an example of your react code and your express code?

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj)?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the github link as its an internal project, but I can tell how its. Its a kraken app, and in server side, if I do, `router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'))`, `ejs` is set as `view engine` in express config, it will return index file to browser with the react code bundled out by `webpack` added to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is recommended to expose an API so that the React interface can update data, e.g. when the user navigates the page, without reloading the whole page. React is built especially with SPAs in mind and a large part of react is dedicated to managing incremental updates to the page structure.

If however you want to supply some amount of data to your react page on load anyway, you can pass it using a script tag and JSON like so:

in your template:

```
<script>
  window._myInitialState = JSON.parse("{initialState|js|j|s}");
<script>
```

(this is using the `js` (JSON.stringify), `j` (JavaScript string) and `s` (don't escape HTML) [builtin dust filters](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/using-filters/)) to render your data. E.g. with `res.locals.initialState` set to

```
    {
      users: [
        { name: "Test" },
        { name: "Toast" },
        { name: "Foo" },
        { name: "Bar" },
      ]
    }
```

it should JSON encode that into the following script:

```html
    <script>
      window._myInitialState = JSON.parse("{\"users\":[{\"name\":\"Test\"},{\"name\":\"Toast\"},{\"name\":\"Foo\"},{\"name\":\"Bar\"}]}");
    <script>
```

With this in your template you should then be able to access `window._myInitialState` in your React code, e.g. to load it in your root component like so:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(window._myInitialState);
  }
```